# podman: map container user to host user for shared volume permissions

Tags: opensuse, podman, gitea

I am trying to set up `gitea` using podman. I would like to have

- the data volume mapped to a host directory, because it allows me to easily inspect and backup the data
- the container process executed by a specific host user

Podman is executed by the root user, mostly because of the problems I had with `podman generate systemd --new` and rootless containers ( see [systemd User= directive not supported, why?](https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions/9642) and [support User= in systemd for running rootless services](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/12778)).

To achieve the mapping with rootfull containers started mapping all the in-use container `uid`s and `gid`s to the host's `gitea user`. I ended up with something like

```
podman run --rm \
    --uidmap=0:$(id -u gitea):1 \
    --gidmap=0:$(id -g gitea):1 \
    --uidmap=1000:$(id -u gitea):1 \
    --gidmap=1000:$(id -g gitea):1 \
    --gidmap=42:$(id -g gitea):1 \
    --volume /srv/gitea/data:/var/lib/gitea \
    docker.io/gitea/gitea:1.18.0-rc1-rootless
```

The output that I get is

```
WARN[0000] Path "/etc/SUSEConnect" from "/etc/containers/mounts.conf" doesn't exist, skipping 
WARN[0000] Path "/etc/zypp/credentials.d/SCCcredentials" from "/etc/containers/mounts.conf" doesn't exist, skipping 
Error: OCI runtime error: runc create failed: unable to start container process: can't get final child's PID from pipe: EOF
```

I succesfully ran other podman containers despite the path warnings, so I think they can be ignored.

I am running `podman version 3.4.7` on openSUSE Leap 15.3 .

How can I run this container, while mapping all the in-use `uid`s and `gid`s to a specific host user/group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause seems to have been trying to map multiple container `uid`s ( and `gid`s ) to the a single `uid`/`gid` to the host. So I was trying to map ( container to host ):

- UID 0 → gitea
- GID 0 → gitea
- UID 1000 → gitea
- GID 1000 → gitea
- GID 42 → gitea

Instead I am know falling back to a different mapping, where just the 1000 UID/GID pair, the one actually running the Gitea app, is mapped to the host user, and others receive a different UID range using

```
    --uidmap=0:10000:999 \
    --gidmap=0:10000:999 \
    --uidmap=1000:$(id -u gitea):1 \
    --gidmap=1000:$(id -g gitea):1 \
```

This means that we have the following mappings

- UIDs 0-999 → 10000-10999
- GIDs 0-999 → 10000-10999
- UID 1000 → gitea
- GID 1000 → gitea

With this change, the container starts up successfully and the permissions on the host are as expected.

Comment: A side-note: Podman 4.3 introduced the options _uid_ and _gid_ that can be used as `--userns=keep-id:uid=$uid,gid=$gid`. That could be used as an alternative to using __--uidmap__ and __--gidmap__ (see https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#39-podman-run-fails-with-error-unrecognized-namespace-mode-keep-iduid1000gid1000-passed)

Comment: Thanks for the info @ErikSjölund, will take a look once openSUSE updates, probably around Leap 15.5, as the latest (Tumbleweed) version has podman 4.2.1 .